# Steganography in JPEG files

Tags: algorithm, jpeg, bufferedimage, steganography

I have a program that successfully reads in an image into a 2 dimensional array, which then goes through a series of DCT steps (transformation, quantization), and then does the reverse to form back the image again.

I am now trying to embed message bits into the quantized coefficients using the LSB way (JSTEG). This does not yet work.

The problem is that everytime i use the DCT process and create the output image (without the embedding process), the quantized coefficients seem to be a value off by 1 from the original image.

For an example:

Original Quant. Coeffs: -27, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, etc

Resultant Quant. Coeffs: -28, 1, 0, 0, 0, etc

Again this is without any Steganography ! (Just ordinary DCT process of a JPEG)

Does anybody know can this be normal where a particular quantized coeffs matrix may be a value off to the same particular quantized coeffs from the original? (such as the e.g. above)

Because this is of course effecting the embedding process, where I would need to extract the bits out of the coeffs (should be same values?) ?

Thanks, I hope this is clear enough on what my problem may be

Comment: What package do you use to save the image? Could it be that saving the image recompresses and alters the coefficients? [Example SO question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799147/dct-coefficients-changed-after-jpeg-saved-to-ios-photo-library)

Comment: Its written in Java. I'm using the standard BufferedImage class from the awt.image package. I simply call the setRGB() method to write the values back to the file. That example seems to be the same problem, but he is using IOS.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not knowledgable with the inner workings of the package. All I can suggest is this naive test. Modify some coefficients keep the array (call it `C1`). Take the inverse transform and keep this modified image in memory (`M1`). Forward transform `M1` and keep this (`C2`). Save `M1` and load it again as `M2`. Now check whether `C1 == C2` and `M1 == M2`. This will tell you whether the transformation process introduces rounding errors (`C1 != C2`) or whether saving the image alters it (`M1 != M2`).

Comment: May I also suggest that you show your code and add the relevant java and awt tags in the question?

Comment: OK thanks for the help. Il see if that works. I could try post the code, but it is too long